# Error while trying to install Node on Ubuntu

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, installation

I am new to ubuntu and programming. I was trying to install nodejs.
I ran

```
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

in the terminal in ubuntu. I got missing firmware warnings. I also got an error of no space left on device. I tried reading up on the error and tried manually removing old kernel versions. But I am still getting the same error. I have no idea how I should approach this issue. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Below is the terminal after I ran the command.

```
dell@dell:~$ sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
[sudo] password for dell: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
nodejs is already the newest version (10.14.2-1nodesource1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 257 not upgraded.
5 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up initramfs-tools (0.122ubuntu8.10) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Setting up linux-firmware (1.157.20) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.18.1
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/skl_dmc_ver1_27.bin  
for module i915 
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/kbl_dmc_ver1_04.bin 
for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/cnl_dmc_ver1_07.bin 
for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/kbl_guc_ver9_39.bin 
for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/bxt_guc_ver9_29.bin 
for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/skl_guc_ver9_33.bin 
for module i915

gzip: stdout: No space left on device
E: mkinitramfs failure cpio 141 gzip 1
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-4.18.1 with 1.
dpkg: error processing package linux-firmware (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit 
status 1
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a 
followup error from a previous failure.
dpkg: dependency problems prevent 
configuration of linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04:
linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04 depends on linux-firmware; however:
Package linux-firmware is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04 (-- 
configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-generic- 
hwe-16.04:
linux-generic-hwe-16.04 depends on linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04 (= 
4.15.0.42.63); however:
Package linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-generic-hwe-16.04 (-- 
configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-signed- 
generic-hwe-16.04:
linux-signed-generic-hwe-16.04 depends on linux-generic-hwe-16.04; 
however:
Package linux-generic-hwe-16.04 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-signed-generic-hwe-16.04 (-- 
configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
PrNo apport report written because the error message indicates its a 
followup error from a previous failure.
No apport report written because MaxReports 
is reached already
      ocessing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.122ubuntu8.10) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.18.1
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/skl_dmc_ver1_27.bin 
for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/kbl_dmc_ver1_04.bin 
for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/cnl_dmc_ver1_07.bin 
for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/kbl_guc_ver9_39.bin 
for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/bxt_guc_ver9_29.bin 
for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/skl_guc_ver9_33.bin 
for module i915

gzip: stdout: No space left on device
E: mkinitramfs failure cpio 141 gzip 1
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-4.18.1 with 1.
dpkg: error processing package initramfs-tools (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit 
status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                          Errors 
were encountered while processing:
linux-firmware
linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04
linux-generic-hwe-16.04
linux-signed-generic-hwe-16.04
initramfs-tools
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Are you able to run `apt-get update` without errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

run this :
`node -v` if it displays a version, then it means you already have the latest version of node installed. Reason is this from your logs:

```
nodejs is already the newest version (10.14.2-1nodesource1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 257 not upgraded.
5 not fully installed or removed.
```

Comment: Yeah, it was already installed, my mistake. But what were all the other errors that came up?

Comment: @Zag i'm not much of a linux user, so not sure. it seems like ubuntu tried to install some other package, and update may be and there wasn't enough space. `Setting up initramfs-tools (0.122ubuntu8.10) ...`

Answer (score 0):

Your logging says you are low on disk space:

`gzip: stdout: No space left on device`

Try to delete some files and try again
You can try the command

`df -h`

to list your free space on your partitions